# set up Caps Lock as a shortcut for changing the input language

Tags: language, input-source, caps-lock

I want to set up Casp Lock as a shortcut for changing the input language. There are some solutions like [this](http://dae.cyberic.eu/blog/select-input-language-by-caps-lock-in-mac-os-x/). But it requires installing some software and doing tricks. Is there a way to do it in a neat way, say through terminal command?

Comment: Could you bind a keyboard shortcut for switching the keyboard? If so, I would recommend using KeyRemap4MacBook and PCKeyboardHack to bind caps lock to that keyboard shortcut. These utilities are vey impressive, and I was able to create a very complex keyboard layout using them along with ukelele.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you can use Caps Lock to change input language without third-party software.
All you need is a custom-made keyboard layout (usually made with [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele) ) that has two alternative sets of characters bound to `Caps lock=on` and `Caps lock=on and Shift=on` states.

Pros: zero-lag, no weird key remapping hacks needed
Cons: buit-in input source indicator becomes useless, looking at the Caps LED is not very convenient for touch-typists.

To mitigate the "cons" I use lightweight third-party app called Capster that changes the icon in the menubar depending on the Caps lock state.
I also use small Applescript to disable Caps lock delay.

I'm using this method for many years and never looked back.

This is my bundle for Russian language (with additional Ukrainian characters bound to alt+key)
https://github.com/falcn/Caps-layout

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, unless someone posts a (possible veery long) command that modifies the keyboard drivers in the same way PCKeyboardHack and KeyRemap4MacBook do, but in general, using these is the way to go.

Comment: I would say use prebuilt tools people have created, used, tested, etc. That ensures you don't mess something up when modifying your operating system.

Answer (score 0):

In case people who get here from search engines don't read the linked post, you can change caps lock to something like F19 with [PCKeyboardHack](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/pckeyboardhack.html.en):

[image]

And then change the shortcut for selecting the next input source to F19:

[image]